# May an adversary be fooled by a random-looking input that in reality is fixed?

Tags: public-key, signature, provable-security, discrete-logarithm, attack

I want to prove the EUF-CMA-security of a signature scheme. It is a variation on an established scheme, therefore I would ideally like to reduce the new-scheme-security to the old-scheme-security.

**the (very abstract) construction**

Let the old scheme be called S and let k denote a number. In S, k is fixed, say k=5. Imagine the new scheme N is identical, only with k becoming random and secret (because it is now related to the key material). So, k=5 is in theory still possible but may just as well be 1,2,3, .. and k=5 is just as likely as k = any other number.

One needs to know k to verify the signature, and k acts similar to a symmetric key. The setting is a group where you want to identify an individual sender but still share symmetric keys.

**the reduction attempt**

An adversary may query oracles for different values of k and the challenger can simply draw them randomly.
However, in the challenge setting, it may obviously not know k, which is secret.
Now, it would be easy to reduce the security of one scheme to the other if the adversary were to be tricked into outputting a signature for k=5. Then the security of N can be reduced to the security of S.

The adversary can not tell from the key material or the signatures or the verification equation that k=5 (because everything still appears random), except if it can break the DLog assumption.

So the **questions** are:

1. An adversary can easily check whether k=5 or k!=5 in the challenge setting by attempting to verify a signature using k=5. Would an adversary realize that it is not interacting with the
   scheme but with a "simulation" if it finds out that k=5 in the challenge setting? (In which case, as far as I understand, it would not
   output a signature but break off the game.) Or is 5 a good a number as any, from the perspective of the adversary?
2. I can not play the game differently for different adversaries, depending on whether they compute k or not, because I know nothing about how A works - correct? (See Katz, Lindell, Introduction to Modern Cryptography, pg.59) Or could I play differently for "DLog-Breakers" and "DLog-Ignorants"?

Comment: "Imagine the new scheme N is identical, only with k becoming random and secret (because it is now related to the key material)."  "One needs to know k to verify the signature"; if $k$ is effectively part of the private key, how can it be used during signature verification?  For the security of signatures, we assume that the adversary knows everything the honest verifier does...

Comment: They could be thinking this would be a system along the lines of HMAC. At least, that's what I think when I read this.

Comment: @Serpent27: I suspect so as well; however, if they are talking about a MAC based on DLog, first off, they should say so, and second off, well, "why, given that there are far more efficient symmetric constructions?"

Comment: I have no idea why.. But it sorta sounds like this is for a video game? or not? "*would not output a signature but break off the game*." A secure signature scheme doesn't need a game or a simulation so I can only assume they mean the kind you play for fun.

Comment: Well, k is not part of *the* private key, because there are really two: an asymmetric key and a symmetric key. The symmetric key is k. The idea is: There is a group sharing a key k. All individual participants have an asymmetric key pair as well. The scheme aims to unite the group authentication with the individual authentication, so a group member will know how to verify the signature (namely, using k) and thereby verify two things: that the communication partner is who they say they are as an individuum and that they are part of the group.

Comment: I'm not sure what's confusing about the "game" or simulation: Why would I not need a simulation or game to prove the security of a signature scheme? Maybe my terminology is wrong? From what I have taught myself, the "attacker querying oracles can not forge a signature"-way of proving security speaks about games, doesn't it? And as far as I know, attackers can execute useless attacks or end the simulation/game. Can't they?

Comment: When using an oracle-based approach the oracle is a system that takes one input and provides an output according to certain rules. This is useful in a proof of security because it makes it easier to see whether the system is secure under certain assumptions. The oracle returns a signature which is *assumed* to be secure because we already know we can create secure signatures. The oracle is a stand-in for an arbitrary but *real* signature scheme.

Comment: Okay; so my understanding is: There is a challenger, there is an adversary, there are some oracles the adversary can query, and this together with a certain procedure is called a game that follows certain rules.  If the attacker realises with more than negligible probability that they are not playing the "real" scheme, but are playing in a simulation, the proof is invalid, because one of the rules is: The game is indistinguishable from the real scheme to an attacker. So if, for example, signatures appear random in the real scheme, so must the oracle-signatures. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would an adversary realize that it is not interacting with the scheme but with a "simulation" if it finds out that k=5 in the challenge setting?

This is commonly stated as [Kerckhoff's Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), which I prefer to cite as Shannon's Maxim (they both stated it, and Shannon's Maxim sounds better). The idea is, the adversary should be *assumed* to know everything about a secure system, except the key, if it is to be considered secure at all. As such, the *adversary must be assumed to know* that you could lie to them about the value of $k$.

Also, a signature scheme could not be considered secure if it involves an oracle *capable of lying* about what signatures are valid or invalid. As such, if the system is to be secure at all, it must behave the same for an attacker as if they were a legitimate verifier.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand the second part and why my concept of proving the scheme secure against an outside attacker who is not even part of the group (please see my above comment) is not the way to go. 
And about Kerckhoff's Principle: I would not be lying, though. The value would really be k=5. Leaving aside the problem that this probably only proves that the system is secure for k=5, I was wondering whether the attacker would wise up to this being a simulation if it found out that k=5 in the challenge epoch, because it would be such a coincidence.

Comment: In that case, while your system may be secure, only someone knowing $k$ could verify a signature. This would be equivalent to signing the message, the encrypting the signature under a normal scheme; or signing only an HMAC hash of the message. The unclear detail here is the *challenger* doesn't draw any oracles. The oracles simply verify (if $k$ is correct) whether a message is valid. For an incorrect $k$ it would always say the signature is invalid (barring collisions, of course).

Comment: With all the lack of clarity with this question, your assumption is correct; that for an attacker knowing $k$ the scheme has the same security s the old scheme $S$; and for an attacker not knowing $k$ the scheme is at least as secure as $S$: it has more security than $S$ if the attacker has difficulty finding $k$, or the same security as $S$ if the attacker can reasonably find $k$.

Comment: Although I might ask, why you're attempting to create signatures only certain people can verify... That kind of seems rather clique-y to me, but I guess you don't want the adversary proving you signed something? That could provide a certain level of plausible-deniability, I guess.

Comment: It is supposed to be clique-y; not necessarily for security reasons, but because I'm trying to analyze whether that would be more efficient in some aspects.

Comment: So, you say my assumption is correct: How do I go about proving this? Can I differentiate between different attackers in a game-based proof?

Comment: And thank you for pointing out the similarity to an encryption - it is not exactly like that because the "encryption" happens in between some signature steps; but that view may help me think about the proof.

Comment: You could differentiate between attackers knowing $k$ and attackers *not* knowing $k$. Beyond that, if they know $k$ you get the underlying signature; therefore proving the security at least equivalent to the signature used. If they don't know $k$ they must decrypt to find the signature (which should be reliant on the difficulty of finding $k$). Therefore, for an attacker not knowing $k$ you have the security of decrypting using $k$, plus the security of the signature scheme. It effectively behaves as an encrypted signature (actually... it *is* an encrypted signature).

Comment: You could also sign an HMAC hash, instead of encrypting the signature. In this case the proof remains the same.

Comment: This is a weird system to prove, to say the least, since to evaluate the security you must compare the security of an attacker trying to *obtain* the signature to verify, with the security of trying to *forge* the signature. It's sort of a comparing apples-to-oranges kind of deal. But if you want to prevent the attacker from *verifying* the signature it's equivalent to breaking the encryption with $k$ as the key. I've been proving the unforgeability, but proving the unverifiability is also of concern (I think...).

Comment: If you want to prove the **unverifiability** it's simply the difficulty of decrypting to find the actual signature; without $k$ it's a decryption problem, so the security is equivalent to that of the encryption algorithm chosen. In this case it's not at *least* as secure as the encryption algorithm, it's *exactly* as secure as the encryption algorithm; since the encryption is the only barrier to verifying the signature.

Comment: `So, you say my assumption is correct: How do I go about proving this? Can I differentiate between different attackers in a game-based proof?` No, you can't differentiate between attackers. You can differentiate between knowing $k$ and not knowing $k$ but you can't make any distinction beyond this. You can't even differentiate between attackers and legitimate users of the system, since the only real distinction is what they know vs what they don't know.

Comment: Humans can identify intent, but even *we* are bad at it. Numbers can't identify intent, only knowledge. Therefore, in encryption we must use knowledge to differentiate; nothing else. That's why you can't distinguish between different attackers using a game-based proof... The game isn't representative of how the system actually works, since it *requires* the attacker to play the game, which they can simply choose not to do if they know the system.

Comment: The ciritical point being that I cannot know whether an attacker can compute, and thus know, k or not if I view them as a black box adversary (unless I differentiate by this _prior_ to the game.) Correct?

Comment: Correct. The only way to find out for sure is for them to compute $k$ and prove they can. That's why its so hard in crypto to prove they cannot. But for a security analysis you can differentiate by *assuming* they start with or without knowledge of $k$.

Comment: Ok, got that. This discussion helped me a lot. Thank you for all your efforts.